# Pronunciation of "punkto"

Tags: pronunciation

My understanding is that Esperanto consonants are all supposed to be pronounced moreorless as they sound individually. However, in certain cases of three consonants in a row, it seems like speakers modify the pronunciation. For example: in the word "punkto"  I hear the n sounded from the back the mouth like the n in the English "ing". Is this pronunciation incorrect? If so, is my first statement indeed correct? If not, what are the rules governing these changes and are there other examples of this sort?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are asking about is called "allophonic variation" in linguistics: It is the phenomenon that the same phoneme is usually pronounced in slightly different ways depending on context.

In Esperanto, allophonic variation also exists, though unlike in other language, it is never obligatory, and it tends to be quite small. One example of a small allophonic variation that non-linguists normally do not even notice is the fact the the /k/ in *kiso* is often pronounced as [k̟], i.e. in a more advanced way (more to the front) than in other positions.

What you ask about is the most noticeable common allophonic variation, namely the change of the phoneme /n/ from its standard pronunciation [n] to [ŋ] before /g/ and /k/. Zamenhof said that this pronunciation is completely natural and should therefore not be fought against, but that it should also not be recommended, as the theoretical norm is that /n/ should always be pronounced as [n].

So this variation in the pronunciation of /n/ is accepted, but it is certainly not obligatory. Some Esperanto speakers (including myself) often do pronounce /n/ as [n] even before [g] and [k], at least in careful pronunciation.

The [Esperanto Wikipedia](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prononco_de_Esperanto) has a good section on allophonic variation:

> **Alofona variado**
>
> La principo "por unu sono unu litero", kiun Zamenhof eldiris en Lingva Respondo de 1891,[11] kontraŭas la ekziston de alofona variado, do de laŭkuntekste malsama prononcado de unusama fonemo. Alofona variado estas fenomeno trovebla en diversaj gradoj en ĉiuj lingvoj de la mondo. Ankaŭ en Esperanto ĝi ne estas tute evitebla: Ekzemple en "kiso" oni nature prononcas la fonemon /k/ iom pli antaŭe ol kutime, do kiel [k̟].[12]
>
> Zamenhof mem fakte en Lingva Respondo de 1911 agnoskis la ekziston de alofona variado (notu ke li ne uzas prononcosciencan terminaron; laŭ tiu devus esti "palatigas" kaj "vele" anstataŭ "moligas" kaj "naze"):
>
> > "Kiel en ĉiuj lingvoj, tiel ankaŭ en Esperanto la sono j ordinare moligas la konsonanton, kiu staras antaŭ ĝi; oni sekve ne devas miri, ke ekzemple en la vorto “panjo” la plimulto de la Esperantistoj elparolas la nj kiel unu molan sonon (simile al la franca gn). Tiel same oni ne miru, ke en praktiko oni ordinare antaŭ g aŭ k elparolas la sonon n naze, aŭ ke antaŭ vokalo oni elparolas la i ordinare kiel ij. Batali kontraŭ tia natura emo en la elparolado ŝajnas al mi afero tute sencela kaj senbezona, ĉar tia elparolado (kiu estas iom pli eleganta, ol la elparolado pure teoria) donas nenian malkompreniĝon aŭ praktikan maloportunaĵon; sed rekomendi tian elparoladon (aŭ nomi ĝin “la sole ĝusta”) ni ankaŭ ne devas, ĉar laŭ la teoria vidpunkto (kiu en Esperanto ofte povas esti ne severe observata, sed neniam povas esti rigardata kiel “erara”) ni devas elparoli ĉiun sonon severe aparte; sekve se ni deziras paroli severe regule, ni devas elparoli “pan-jo”, “san-go”, “mi-a”.[13] "
>
> Konforme kun ĉi tiu eldiro de Zamenhof, en la nature evoluinta prononca normo de Esperanto ne ekzistas deviga alofona variado, kaj ĝenerale percepteblas tendenco minimumigi la alofonan variadon.[8][14] Do ekzemple ne ekzistas regulo, ke /n/ antaŭ /g/ kaj /k/ devas esti prononcata kiel [ŋ]. Oni same rajtas prononci ĝin kiel [n], kaj kelkaj parolantoj aparte zorgas pri la prononco [n] ĉe klara parolado kun zorga prononco.
>
> Aparte vaste pridiskutata estis la alofona variado ĉe vokaloj. La Plena Analiza Gramatiko preskribis regulojn por la vasteco de /e/ kaj /o/ depende de la kunteksto: Por silaboj sen fina konsonanto ĝi preskribis la pli malvastajn prononcojn [e] kaj [o], dum por silaboj kun fina konsonanto ĝi preskribis la pli vastajn prononcojn [ɛ] kaj [ɔ]. Tiuj preskriboj tamen ne iĝis parto de la ĝenerale akceptata prononca normo.[12][15] Anstataŭe oni sen laŭkuntekstaj reguloj akceptas por /e/ kaj /o/ ĉiujn prononcojn inter [e] kaj [ɛ] kaj inter [o] kaj [ɔ], kaj la tute mezaj prononcoj [e̞] kaj [o̞] estas rigardataj kiel plej modelaj.

Answer (score 7):

According to the PMEG, it's an acceptable alteration:

> Kiam N staras antaŭ gingiva aŭ vela sono, oni emas ŝanĝi N en gingivan
>   sonon (malgranda diferenco), aŭ velan sonon (granda diferenco), por
>   faciligi la elparolon: *tranĉi, manĝi, longa, banko* k.a. Tio estas
>   senproblema, ĉar ne ekzistas gingiva aŭ vela nazaj sonoj, kun kiuj N
>   povus konfuziĝi.

In English:

> When N is before a [laminal] or velar sound, The N tends to become a
>   [laminal] sound (small difference), or a velar sound (large
>   difference), to ease pronounciation: *tranĉi, manĝi, longa, banko*,
>   etc. It's unproblematic because there are no [laminal] or velar
>   nasal sounds which N could be confused for.

People generally don't mind or even notice the velarization of N before velar stops, generally because most people do it. It happens in French, Spanish, Hungarian, Japanese, English, German, etc. It's a fairly common form of assimilation.